# Link not working with frame tag in html

Tags: html, css

I need 3 pages merged in one single page with frame tag so I used a frametag with the src attribute but its not working, is frame tag now obsolete or is it just me?
Here's the code

```
<html>
    <style ="text/css"> </style>
    <frameset cols="33.3%,33.3%,33.3%">
        <frame src="1.html">
           <p>hello</p>
           <frame>
                <p>productivity</p>
           </frame>
           <frame>
                <p> Entertainment</p>
     </frameset>
```

Comment: I don't see an src attribute?

Comment: But @KyleHodgetts I need another webpage displaying on to the other webpage with frame tag ie: <frame src="page.html>

Comment: Is the code I've copied into the question from your comment an accurate representation of what you're using?

Comment: @KyleHodgetts Sorry there was mistake,now its the exact code I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

All the frame pages should follow these mandatory rules:

- Page containing <frameset> should not include <html> and/or <body> tags.
- The <frame> tags must be close using either <frame></frame> or <frame />.
- The <frame> tags must have an **'src'** attribute and without *src* attribute, the space allocated for it will be displayed as a blank page.

For your need the following will be the required answer:

**Frame.html**

```
<frameset cols="33.3%,33.3%,33.3%">
     <frame src="1.html" />
     <frame src="2.html" />
     <frame src="3.html" />
</frameset>
```

**1.html**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Hello</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**2.html**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Productivity</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**3.html**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Entertainment</p>
    </body>
</html>
```